# Formatting html data on Client End using jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I need a regex which will handle formatting for text entered in text-editor.

See this html

```
<p class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom:0cm;margin-bottom:.0001pt;line-height:
normal;mso-pagination:none;mso-layout-grid-align:none;text-autospace:none;text-align:center;"><b><span style="font-   size:14.0pt;font-family:&quot;Times-Roman&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;;mso-bidi-font-family:
 Times-Roman;color:#1B1E20">-- Michael Hirst</span></b><span style="font-size:
14.0pt;font-family:&quot;Times-Roman&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;;mso-bidi-font-family:Times-Roman;
color:#1B1E20">, creator, writer, and executive producer,&nbsp;Vikings</span><o:p></o:p></p>
```

expected output:

```
<p style="text-align:center;"><span>--Michael Hirst</span></b><span>creator, writer, and executive producer,Vikings</span>
```

I need to remove class attributes from the html. and for inline style i need to except only text-align.
after formatting this i need to except few tags from only like we do in php using strip_tags

```
 strip_tags($html,"<b><h2><h3><h4><strong><div><p><br><ul><li><ol><blockquote>")
```

what would be the regex for doing this. I am newbie to this regex!!

Answer (score 0):

Don't try parsing html with regex. Have a search on SO - there are many examples of why not. As you have tagged your question with jquery you could use something like this as a starting point:

```
var $html = $('.MsoNormal + span').html();
$('p').css('text-align','center').append($html);
```

[DEMO here](http://jsfiddle.net/garyh/WzA3X/)

Comment: See data is coming from text-editor. and always it can't be MsoNormal there. there can be any format. i just want to format it . As i have mentioned in my question. It's about formatting html.

Comment: @Creator If the html data is just in a text editor how does using javascript or jquery help to solve the problem?

Comment: When user post it. I can grab his input and format it on client side and pass to server side. @garyh